# Python Script to iterate numerous, single-band rasters for arcpy.CompositeBands

Tags: arcpy, raster, band, composite

I have a large collection of single-band geotiffs (NIR, Green, and Red) that I would like to composite using a Python script. The goal is to iterate through multiple folders in a main directory, identify each tiff as band1, band2, band3 to input into CompositeBands_management, and do this for every raster scene. To clarify, each image number, i.e. scene, has three single-band tiffs associated. For example, the naming convention is: TTC2500_Green_Channel_8.TIF where TTC2500 is the image number.

So far, my script can go through each folder and identify the specific bands based on the filename but I am having difficulty bringing them into the tool. The attached script has the Composite tool commented out but the result is a printed list of each geotiff. Any thoughts on how to move from here into an automated processing method to output new false color composite geotiffs?

```
import arcpy
import os
from arcpy.sa import *
from arcpy import env

env.workspace=(r"C:\Users\cc\Desktop\tcamPractice")
env.overwriteOutput = True

outws=(r"C:\Users\cc\Desktop\tcamPractice\false")
folders=arcpy.ListWorkspaces()

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(r"C:\Users\cc\Desktop\tcamPractice"):

    for raster in files:
        rasterlist=arcpy.ListRasters("*", "TIF")
        outraster=outws+"comp.tif"
        if raster.find("Green")>0:
            band1=raster
            print band1
        elif raster.find("Red")>0:
            band2=raster
            print band2
        elif raster.find("Nir")>0:
            band3=raster
            print band3
        #arcpy.CompositeBands_management([[band3;band2;band1]], outraster)
```